# How to scan a partial /23 subnet with NMAP?

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

I would like to partially scan /23 subnets with NMAP. For example, the subnet 192.168.0.0/23 ranges from IP address 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.1.255.
I don't want to perform a complete subnet scan, but only a partially scan. For example scanning from IP 192.168.0.30 to 192.168.1.240.

I'm using NMAP version 7.60 on Ubuntu OS.

I can scan the complete subnet with this code

```
nmap -sn -host-timeout 300 -n 192.168.0.0/23
```

However, I would like to scan not the complete subnet.

How to scan a specific range, for example from IP 192.168.0.30 to 192.168.1.240? Notice that the 3rd octet is changing since I'm scanning a /23 subnet.

I also tried

```
nmap -sn -host-timeout 300 -n 192.168.0-1.30-240
```

but in that version I'm missing some IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NMAP, you can specify multiple IP addresses/ranges separated by a whitespace.

Since your example only includes 192.168.0.* and 192.168.1.* (where * is an arbitrary range), you can simply enumerate them like this:

```bash
nmap -sn -host-timeout 300 -n 192.168.0.30-255 192.168.1.0-240
```